# How to remove variables in large dataset i Rstudio?

Tags: rstudio

I'm trying to permanently remove some of the variables in the dataframe 'd' individually, as they are no longer useful.

New to Rstudio and coding. Using Rstudio, version 0.99.491 on Windows. I am using a secure server, so downloading packages are not an option. 
I have a very large dataset 'd' containing 122 variables of ~450.000 rows.

I'm using a Danish version of the program, so the error messages have been translated by me and might be incorrect.

I have tried:

Option 1:

```
> rm (d$variable121)
Error in rm(d$variable121):... must contain name or character strings
```

Option 2:

```
> rm('d$variable121')
Warning meaasage: 
in rm('d$variable121'): object 'd$variable121' not found
```

Option 3:

```
> rm (list=c('d$variable121', 'd$variable122'))
Warning messages: 
1: in  rm (list=c('d$variable121', 'd$variable122')) object 'variable 121' not found. 
2: in  rm (list=c('d$variable121', 'd$variable122')) object 'variable 122' not found.
```

I'm able to remove other dataframes, but not any variable in the 'd' dataframe.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data frame is called `d` with four columns and you want to delete variables with names `var1` and `var3`. You can do

```
> d <- data.frame(var1=1:10, var2=2:11, var3=3:12, var4=4:13)
> d
   var1 var2 var3 var4
1     1    2    3    4
2     2    3    4    5
3     3    4    5    6
4     4    5    6    7
5     5    6    7    8
6     6    7    8    9
7     7    8    9   10
8     8    9   10   11
9     9   10   11   12
10   10   11   12   13
> dropped <- c("var1", "var3")
> d[, !(names(d) %in% dropped)]
   var2 var4
1     2    4
2     3    5
3     4    6
4     5    7
5     6    8
6     7    9
7     8   10
8     9   11
9    10   12
10   11   13
```

Comment: Perfect. And if i add a
> d <- d[!(names(d) %in% dropped)] 
I can permanently remove them. 
Thanks :)